# How many lure modules can a trainer drop simultaneously?

Tags: pokemon-go

We're thinking to do some on-ground campaign with Pokemon Go. Basically, we will have a leader (trainer) who will be purchasing lots of lure modules and dropping them at Pokestops to create crowd engagement.

The question is, say, if there are 3 Pokestops at a location, can the same trainer drop 3 modules at all 3 Pokestops at the same time?

Comment: I cannot imagine that there is a limit (besides travelling between the stops) in the number of lures you can deploy

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A player can drop as many lures at any simultaneous moment as they have in their inventory (and thus use them), however - A PokéStop can only have **one** lure module at a time.

Since a PokéStop can only have one lure at a time, the next person to deploy a lure will have to wait until the current one runs out before being allowed to use his.

**tl;dr** 
Deploy away!